# Using Gradle 2.x and Maven plugin, how do I find the names of published poms?

Tags: maven, gradle

If I apply the 'maven' plugin, I get the 'uploadArchives' task, as well as getting a pom generated for my archive(s).

If I don't do anything special, the pom on disk is 'build/poms/pom-default.xml'

However, when the archive is uploaded, the pom is uploaded with it... only under a different name.  Suppose my project was 'p', and the archive result was 'p-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar'.  When that is published, the 'pom-default.xml' files is published with the jar as 'p-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom'.

I also know that you can set the name of the pom to generate, etc., etc.

What I need to be able to do, programmatically in a plugin, is find out which pom(s) got published, and the name(s) of said published items.

Where is this info?